# How to make an NFC tag write protected?

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am building a application that writes and reads from NFC tags,but I need the data to be not modified after writing on it.
I tried MakeReadOnly() ,but I don'tknow why it didn't work !

```
     protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if(intent.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG))
    {
            Toast.makeText(this,"NFC intent!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// After detecting a tag on my system, I can get an tag object to write or read from it
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            NdefMessage ndefMessage = creatNdefMessage(StudentId.getText()+"");
            writeNdefMessage(tag,ndefMessage);
        // it writes on the tag but cannot makeit read only !!!

       try{ Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if (ndef != null) {
            ndef.connect();
            if (ndef.canMakeReadOnly()) {
              Toast.makeText(this,"can make it read only !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               ndef.makeReadOnly();
              }
             ndef.close();
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     }
       }
```

In this code, I can check that it accesses the if statement (ndef.canMakeReadOnly()),and this means that the tag can be red only if I call the MakeReadOnly method, but after running it still I can overwrite the tag!

please help ..

Comment: `canMakeReadOnly()` doesn't actually try to set the tag to read-only, it only performs a check on the appropriate bits. I would check the return value of `makeReadOnly()` to see if it succeeded. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html#makeReadOnly()

Comment: Thank you , yes I know this information , the canMakeReadOnly() method returns ( true ) ,this means it can be read only if I call the MakeReadOnly() ,but actually it doesn't work !

Comment: @henrycjc  and I checked the website too.

Comment: Which tag type is this?

Comment: Mifare 1k S50 MF1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/459579/thomasrs

Comment: @Dua'aAl-helou Yes, but as I said, please check the result of `makeReadOnly()`, too! It is possible that the tag does not support making it read-only, also. Maybe try with a few other types of tags if you can.

Comment: @henrycjc I will thank you,then will reply here.